# Colouring Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I need some help on this. Assume that we have ten colors to choose from. For each of the following questions, assume that the vertices are distinguishable. Where two adjacent vertices cannot be colored the same color.

How many ways are there to color K 10?
I was thinking 10*10 on this

How many ways are there to color E 10?
I was thinking 10P10 here

How many ways are there to color K 12? 
Not sure on the last three how to get going.

How many ways are there to color K 5?

How many ways are there to color K 2,6?

Let me know if I'm on the right track for the first two and how to approach the last three.

Comment: What are you thinking of to arrive at $10\cdot 10$? I suggest $10!$ for the first.

Comment: Are you talking about the classical graph-coloring problem where 2 adjacent vertices can't have the same color?

Comment: @JGab yes thats right

Comment: K12 and K5 are basically the same than K10 with an extra factor to account for the mismatch in color and vertices count.
I don't understand what is K 2,6?

Comment: What is $E_{10}$?

Comment: @N.S. E10 is the empty graph of 10 distinct points all disconnected from each other.

Comment: Ty, I am used with the Null graph notation ;)

Answer (score 0):

**K_{10}** You have 10 choices for the first vertex, 9 for the second, and so on. [or you have ONE coloring, unique up to permutations of vertices, how many permutations are there?]

**K_{12}** Can two vertices have the same color?

**K_5** You have $5$ vertices. 10 choices for first, 9 for the second, ..., 6 for the fifth.

**K_{2,6}** Lets say that the two sets of vertices are $\{ u_1,u_2 \}$ and $\{v_1,.., v_6 \}$.

*Case 1:* $u_1,u_2$ have the same color. You have 10 choices for this color, and 9 choices of colors for each $v_i$.

*Case 2:* $u_1,u_2$ have different colors. You have $10\cdot 9$ choices for these colors, and 8 choices of colors for each $v_i$.

**E_{10}** You have 10 choices for the first vertex. How many choices do you have next?